# using Microsoft.VisualStudio "using directive is unnecessary"

Tags: c#

In the code, I've put in

```
String name = Interaction.InputBox("test", "test", "test", -1 -1);
```

I've added the `using Microsoft.VisualBasic` tag at the top of the program and *added the reference* in the solution explorer. It still doesn't work.

Comment: If you remove the using directive on the top, and use it like this String name = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("test", "test", "test", -1 -1); Does it work?!

Comment: This works for me. Do you have any other error messages. i.e. when building the solution or in intellisense?

Comment: It works for me too with no problem. Check the reference for 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' again. Is there some other class 'Interaction' in your scope? Where do you jump to when the cursor is on 'Interaction' and you press [F12]?

Comment: When I hover over Interaction is says "the name interaction does not exist in the current context"

Comment: `the name interaction does not exist in the current context` You sure the first letter of `interaction` is lower case like that?

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

make sure you typed the reference right `using Microsoft.VisualBasic;`

and try to do this:

```cs
String name = "";
name = Interaction.InputBox("Type your name:", "Title - Name");
```

Comment: Im not sure why you added two extra parameters, I dont think you will need them.